SGX Disabled by BIOS Causing Slow Ubuntu 22.04 Boot
I experience long boot times on my Ubuntu 22.04 system, and the boot process often gets stuck on the message: SGX disabled by BIOS.
When I checked the BIOS settings, the only available options for SGX (Software Guard Extensions) are Disabled and Software Controlled. I don’t want to keep waiting for this message to clear every time I boot up.
How can I resolve this issue and improve my boot time?
